# Spring Annotation @WebMvcTest does not work in an app that has Jpa repositories

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test-mvc

I have a Spring App that uses JPA repositories (`CrudRepository` interfaces). When I try to test my controller using the new Spring test syntax `@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)`, it fails coz it tries to instantiate one of my service class that uses JPA Repository, does anyone has any clues on how to fix that? The app works when I run it.

Here is the error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.myapp.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.myapp.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myapp.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Please share your pom.xml and complete stack trace to deep dive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the doc

> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests (i.e. @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver beans but not @Component, @Service or @Repository beans).

This annotion only apply on the Spring MVC components.

If you are looking to load your full application configuration and use MockMVC, you should consider `@SpringBootTest` combined with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` rather than this annotation.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I ended up using the method you mentioned, and it works.

Comment: A link to the docs. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html

Answer (score 2):

I faced this same problem. Using `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to unit test a Rest Controller by implementing junit 5 and using `@SpringJUnitConfig` along with `@WebMvcTest`. I am using Spring Boot 2.4.5 and this is my example:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
@WebMvcTest(controllers = OrderController.class)
class OrderControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    // This is a Mock bean of a Spring Feign client that calls an external Rest Api
    @MockBean
    private LoginServiceClient loginServiceClient;

    // This is a Mock for a class which has several Spring Jpa repositories classes as dependencies
    @MockBean
    private OrderService orderService;

    @DisplayName("should create an order")
    @Test
    void createOrder() throws Exception {

        OrderEntity createdOrder = new OrderEntity("123")

        when(orderService.createOrder(any(Order.class))).thenReturn(createdOrder);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/orders").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content("{orderId:123}"))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))TODO: here it will go the correlationId
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.orderId").value("123"));
    }
}
```

Please only use `@SpringBootTest` when you are implementing integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should manual config Data Jpa(https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.java-config) then use @Import annotation in test file instead of use @SpringBootTest to load all bean in system that will very expense(time and resource) when run test